# how to reduce value in loop

Tags: loops, go, if-statement

I want to make simple program to count debt installment for 5 years installment.
The requirements is :

1. The 1st and 2nd Year the bank interest is 8%
2. The 3rd year of bank interest is 9%
3. The 4th and 5th year the bank interest is 10%

and the output should be :

1. The value of 1st and 2nd installment
2. remaining debt before 3rd year
3. the value of 3rd installment
4. remaining debt before 4th year
5. the value of 4th and 5th installment

and here's my code :

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var debt = 200000000
    var installment int

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        var remainDebt int
        if i < 3 {
            installment = (debt / 5) + (debt * 8 / 100)
            remainDebt = debt - installment
            fmt.Println("Year", i, "is", installment)
            fmt.Println("Remaining debt is", remainDebt)
        } else if i == 3 {
            installment = (debt / 5) + (debt * 9 / 100)
            remainDebt = debt - installment
            fmt.Println("Year", i, "is", installment)
            fmt.Println("Remaining debt is", remainDebt)

        } else if i > 3 {
            installment = (debt / 5) + (debt * 10 / 100)
            fmt.Println("Year", i, "is", installment)

        }

    }
}
```

And the output from my code is :

```
Year 1 is 56000000
Remaining debt is 144000000
Year 2 is 56000000
Remaining debt is 144000000
Year 3 is 58000000
Remaining debt is 142000000
Year 4 is 60000000
Year 5 is 60000000
```

I don't know why the remaining debt from each year are wrong. So, I guess that either I am using wrong syntax or I am trying to do something that can not be done. Maybe most likely experienced people will see right away what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var remainDebt int` this line should be before the for loop and it's starting value should be debt value. In your code, each iteration it becomes it's default value, 0. But it should be keep reducing in each iteration of your loop.

And line `remainDebt = debt - instalment` should be corrected as below. Because you should reduce Capital amount you paid of the loan, not the instalment with interest.

```
`remainDebt = remainDebt - debt / 5`
```

You can see corrected code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/4nlROmpHlLz)